# DrawerLayout widget background change

Tags: android, google-maps, drawerlayout

I am using DrawerLayout widget along with google maps.

when I scroll my list view my backgroud is being changed. and when I click on list view it is changing back to my default background

My intial listview

[image]

on drag/scroll

[image]

On Select

[image]

xml Code:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer1"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="#333"
    android:paddingLeft="15sp"
    android:paddingRight="15sp"
    />
```

java code -

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
     actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your XML `ListView` set `android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"`

Java code `listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);`